# Embedding Gecko engine into a Java desktop application

Tags: java, desktop-application, gecko

I'm currently doing some research into the possibility of embedding the Gecko engine into a Java desktop application. I've seen some tools available such as JavaXPCOM but I'm more interested in the limitations of this. 
I need to have access to the inner workings of the Gecko engine such as how HTML and CSS are combined to render the web page.

The stem of my research is to find a way, using Gecko, to group certain elements within a web form and represent these as well as a list of all of their attributes.

Are there any readily available tools/APIs that give this level of access to the Gecko engine? Or would this require using the Gecko source rather than an API?

Comment: have you solved it out?